# Titanium Close Window and Open New One

Tags: titanium

I am building an iOS application in Titanium.  The first window is a login page.  When the user inputs their username and password, those values are sent to a PHP file for authentication.

If the user is authenticated - i.e. they have a unique username/password combo, I want the current window to close and the new window to open.

The values are being sent to the PHP file and the user is being authenticated; however, when the code that close the current window runs (`Titanium.UI.currentWindow.close`), throws an error indicating that file that opens the new window doesn't exist.  The file referencing the new window does exist though.

I have moved the code that appears to be causing the error into many places but with the same result.

```js
var loginReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

loginReq.onload = function()
{
    var json = this.responseText;
    var response = JSON.parse(json);
    if (response.logged == true)
    {
        alert("Welcome " + response.name + ". Your email is: " + response.email);
        username.value = '';
        password.value = '';
        //This creates the new window after user authentication.
        var menuPage = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        title: "Menu",
        tabBarHidden: false,
        url: 'menuPage.js'
        });
        //This is supposed to close the current window.
        Titanium.UI.currentWindow.close();
        //This is supposed to open the new window.
        menuPage.open();
    }
    else
    {
        alert(response.message);
    }
};
```

Comment: Sometimes `Titanium.UI.currentWindow` does not return the current Window. Try to pass the `Window` in your network file or write network's onload in your window as a callback.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of closing the window first, and then opening the new one, you should first open the new window, and once opened, close the old one from the new window.

```
menuPage.open({closeWindow: function(){ 
    curWin.close(); }
});
```

Then, in `menuPage.js`, watch for the the `open` event, and once that is fired, call the function you passed to `menuPage.js`.

I would however recommend diving into Alloy. This method is **very** outdated.

In Alloy you would do it like this:

```
Alloy.createController('menuPage', {closeWindow: function(){ 
    $.getView().close();
});
```

In menupage:

```
$.getView().addEventListener('open',args.closeWindow());
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this to open a window

```
var menuPage = require('menuPage');
win = new menuPage({title:''});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you using Alloy:

file *windowlogin.xml*

```html
<Alloy>
 <Window id="window_login">
  <TextField id="txt_username"></TextField>
  <TextField id="txt_password"></TextField>
  <Button title="Login" id="btn_login"></Button>
 </Window>
</Alloy>
```

file windowlogin.js

```js
$.btn_login.addEventListener("click", function(e){
 var loginUrl = "http://domain.com/login";
 var dataLogin = {
  username: $.txt_username.value,
  password: $.txt_password.value
 };
 var loginReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

 loginReq.onload = function()
 {
     var json = this.responseText;
     var response = JSON.parse(json);
     if (response.logged == true)
     {
         alert("Welcome " + response.name + ". Your email is: " + response.email);
         username.value = '';
         password.value = '';
         //This creates the new window after user authentication.
         var menuPage = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
   title: "Menu",
   tabBarHidden: false,
   url: 'menuPage.js'
   });
   //This is supposed to open the new window.
         menuPage.open();
         //This is supposed to close the current window.
         $.window_login.close();
     }
     else
     {
         alert(response.message);
     }
 };
 
 loginReq.open("POST", loginUrl);
 loginReq.send(dataLogin);
});
```